# Extract information on twitter rate limit api with python twitter tools

Tags: python, twitter

I am new to python and I am trying to extract the rate limit and remaining status of my application for users/show and users/lookup

```
t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(token, token_key, con_secret, con_secret_key))
x = t.application.rate_limit_status()
```

## works

```
print(x['resources']['users']
```

but when I try and extract user/show and user/lookup specifically it fails

```
print(x['resources']['users'] ['/users/lookup']
```

I thought it might be something to do with the / so tried variations of `['users']['lookup']` for example but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you edit you question to display the result of your various `print`. Incl. error message if there is one. Have you an idea of the _type_ of `x['resources']` and `x['resources']['users']` (probably a _dictionary-like_ object for the former and an _string_ for the latter?)

Comment: `x['resources']['users']['/users/lookup']` works for me, if it's written with the space and lack of bracket like above, I can see why it doesn't work but otherwise we probably need more information